# sitecore media item icon incorrect after upgrade

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

My sitecore environment has been upgraded from 6.6(update-2) to 6.6(updated-5),after that i found that the media item icon(doc,docx,pdf) does not show correct. Example: the .doc file there does not show the correct word icon, it shows another document icon instead.

I have already deleted all the temp/IconCache there, but still bad luck.

has anyone met the same issue? how to resolve it.

Any help, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible your icon set has either upgraded or downgraded to the V2 set of icons supplied? See here to find out about tge icon sets: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Morten-Ljungberg-Sitecore-Whats-New/Posts/2010/01/New-icons-in-Sitecore-62.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar issue on 6.5 where the media icons suddenly don't work, we ended up manually setting the values in the web.config as below.

```
<mediaType name="Excel Document" extensions="xls">
    <mimeType>application/vnd.ms-excel</mimeType>
    <forceDownload>true</forceDownload>
    <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/xls</sharedTemplate>
    <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/xls</versionedTemplate>
  <thumbnails>
        <generator type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaThumbnailGenerator, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <extension>png</extension>                 
    </generator>
        <staticFile>/Css/images/icons/xlsx_16x16.png</staticFile>
  </thumbnails>
</mediaType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue, but I have found that unzipping the icons can sometimes fix this problem (though I haven't expirienced this issue that often or in the latest version 6.5+).

But you should be able to see an error in the log if it can't find the files and then unzipping them will help. This could be because of file access issues, but not sure.